# Using rgl package in R to measure the volume of an irregular object

Tags: r, volume, rgl

I have vertices (x,y,z coordinates) of an irregular object (all normals point outward) and I would like to calculate its volume.   With small objects with just a handful of vertices, I can find the volume by calculating the volume of tetrahedrons for each triangle on the surface with respect to a reference point.   I have a script that will do that for small number of faces and identifying the faces and order of the points is not too difficult.  However, for a large number of points, identifying each group of 3 points is challenging and time consuming.  I think my first problem is that I need to convert my vertices into a mesh but I don't know how to do that.  I have tried several commands in the rgl package but I'm not getting anywhere and I'm not understanding this step.

Below is a sample of my data.  For each set of points, I slice my object and identify 6 vertices.  plot3d(x,y,z) works nicely.

```
index   x   y   z   point
1   -225.64 0.3 427.91  1
2   -225.64 0.3 233.32  2
3   -39.83  0.3 44.62   3
4   45.7    0.3 41.67   4
5   228.56  0.3 236.26  5
6   228.56  0.3 427.91  6
7   -227.47 75  427.52  1
8   -224.52 75  244.72  2
9   -77.05  75  82.56   3
10  73.36   75  82.56   4
11  229.68  75  232.92  5
12  229.68  75  427.52  6
13  -226.37 85  425.78  1
14  -224.75 85  236.55  2
15  -84.08  85  92.6    3
16  84.08   85  92.06   4
17  227.98  85  238.16  5
18  226.37  85  427.4   6
19  -226.37 95  426.39  1
20  -226.37 95  235.54  2
21  -95.4   95  102.91  3
22  93.78   95  102.91  4
23  226.37  95  235.54  5
24  236.37  95  426.39  6
25  -229.6  105 428.21  1
26  -224.75 105 240.59  2
27  -105.1  105 112.81  3
28  106.72  105 112.81  4
29  226.37  105 237.35  5
30  226.37  105 426.59  6
31  -226.37 115 426.59  1
32  -226.37 115 237.35  2
33  -114.8  115 122.52  3
34  114.8   115 124.14  4
35  227.98  115 237.35  5
36  226.37  115 426.59  6
37  -224.75 125 426.59  1
38  -226.37 125 235.74  2
39  -124.5  125 133.84  3
40  122.89  125 135.46  4
41  226.37  125 235.74  5
42  226.37  125 426.59  6
43  -226.37 135 428.21  1
44  -226.37 135 237.35  2
45  -134.2  135 143.54  3
46  135.82  135 143.54  4
47  226.37  135 237.35  5
48  226.37  135 426.59  6
49  -226.37 145 428.21  1
50  -226.37 145 237.35  2
51  -145.54 145 153.25  3
52  142.29  145 154.87  4
53  226.37  145 237.35  5
54  226.37  145 426.59  6
55  -226.37 155 428.21  1
56  -226.37 155 237.35  2
57  -174.63 155 185.4   3
58  174.63  155 185.4   4
59  226.37  155 237.35  5
60  226.37  155 426.59  6
```

Comment: Is your object convex ?

Comment: Yes, all interior angles are <180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `rgl` has a function that you need, but if the object is convex, `geometry::convhulln` can do what you want.  Let's assume that `obj` contains the data you showed, then this calculates the volume of the convex hull:

```
xyz <- obj[c("x", "y", "z")]
library(geometry)
hull <- convhulln(xyz, options = "FA")
hull$vol
```

This gives 20389437.  The volume of the rectangular prism containing all of your points is 27863952, so that looks about right.

If your object is not convex, then maybe the `alphashape3d` package has something that would help you.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a better method than I was using and it actually solves another problem that I had not yet begun to work on (that is: reduce the height to get a particular desired volume).  Many thanks.